# Powershell XML - Iterating Through Parent Nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I am writing a Powershell Script which interrogates Active Directory based on an XML configuration file that looks something like this:

```
<domains>
    <domain name="DOMAIN.INTERNAL" exclude="false">
        <orgunit name="OU1" exclude="false"/>
        <orgunit name="OU2" exclude="false">
            <orgunit name="OU3" exclude="false"/>
            <orgunit name="OU4" exclude="false"/>
            <orgunit name="OU5" exclude="true"/>
        </orgunit>
        <host name="HOST1" exclude="false"/>
        <host name="HOST2" exclude="true" />
        <host name="HOST3" exclude="true" />
    </domain>
    <domain name="SUB.DOMAIN.INTERNAL" exclude="false">
        <orgunit name="OU6" exclude="false">
            <orgunit name="OU7" exclude="false">
                <orgunit name="OU8" exclude="false">
                    <host name="HOST4" exclude="false" />
                </orgunit>
            </orgunit>
        </orgunit>
        <host name="HOST5" exclude="false"/>
        <orgunit name="OU7" exclude="true" />
    </domain>
</domains>
```

I am loading the xml file, setting the xpath and then selecting the orgunit nodes that don't have children:

```
$currentPath=Split-Path ((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value).MyCommand.Path
[xml]$configFile = Get-Content "$currentPath\WindowsUpdateOMatic.xml"

foreach ($domain in $configFile.domains.domain) {

    $xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//orgunit[@exclude=`"false`"][not (*)]/@name")

    foreach($node in Select-Xml -Xpath $xpath $configFile){

        # Find parent nodes
        $node.Node.ParentNode
    }
}
```

My plan is to iterate through the the parent org unit nodes so that I can create the full distinguished name of an OU, e.g. "OU=bar,OU=foo,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=internal".

Then I can query the OU in active directory and retrieve host machines within it.

The trouble is, the value of $node.Node.ParentNode doesn't return anything. Trying various things I did get it to return "InputStream" but I can't reproduce that just now.

I'm fairly new to Powershell, I appreciate it looks like I'm probably trying to run before I can walk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have, in-part, managed to answer my own question.

The xpath in my example is wrong because it is selecting an attribute. Changing:

```
$xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//orgunit[@exclude=`"false`"][not (*)]/@name")
```

To:

```
$xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//orgunit[@exclude=`"false`"][not (*)]")
```

Means that `$node.Node.ParentNode.ToString()` returns `orgunit` if the parent element is an org unit.

All I need to do now is figure out how to recurse up the tree until I get a parent that != 'orgunit'.

I figure that will be a `do while` or `do until` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
function ConvertFrom-ADXmlToDN ($Element) {

    $DNparent = ""

    #Get parent DN - Recursion
    if(($Element.ParentNode -ne $null) -and ($Element.ParentNode.LocalName -ne 'domains')) { 
        $DNparent = ",$(ConvertFrom-ADXmlToDN -Element $Element.ParentNode)"
    }

    #Convert to LDAP path  
    switch($Element.LocalName) {
        "host" { "CN=$($Element.GetAttribute("name"))$DNparent" }
        "orgunit" { "OU=$($Element.GetAttribute("name"))$DNparent" }
        "domain" { 
            "DC=$($Element.GetAttribute("name") -split '\.' -join ',DC=')$DNparent"
        }
    }
}

#Sampledata
$ou = $xml.domains.domain[1].orgunit[0]
$machine = $xml.domains.domain[1].orgunit[0].orgunit.orgunit.host
ConvertFrom-ADXmlToDN -Element $ou
ConvertFrom-ADXmlToDN -Element $machine

OU=OU6,DC=SUB,DC=DOMAIN,DC=INTERNAL
CN=HOST4,OU=OU8,OU=OU7,OU=OU6,DC=SUB,DC=DOMAIN,DC=INTERNAL
```

Usage:

```
ConvertFrom-ADXmlToDN -Element $node.Node
```

Small suggestion. You first loop through the xml file to find the domains, then you loop through it again to find xpath(with domain name specified).

As an alternative to `Select-XML`, you could use `$domain.SelectNodes($xpath)`. But you would have to rewrite the xpath to match the fact that you're starting from a domain-element and not the root xml-element. Like:

```
foreach ($domain in $xml.domains.domain) {

    $xpath = ".//orgunit[@exclude='false'][not (*)]"

    foreach($node in $domain.SelectNodes($xpath)) {

        # Get DN
        ConvertFrom-ADXmlToDN -Element $node
    }

}

OU=OU1,DC=DOMAIN,DC=INTERNAL
OU=OU3,OU=OU2,DC=DOMAIN,DC=INTERNAL
OU=OU4,OU=OU2,DC=DOMAIN,DC=INTERNAL
```

Comment: Thanks. That's not dissimilar from what I've wound up with so far - except I was iterating through parent elements and building up an "FDQN" for each org unit and then throwing that into a function to convert FDQN to DN. Your way looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is what I came up with although I appreciate it's not as clean as Frode. F's answer:

```
clear-host
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module D:\Code\infrastructure\Scripts\PowershellModules\PSWindowsUpdate 

function FDQNtoDN {
    param([string]$FDQN)

    [string]$dn = $null
    [int]$index = 0         
    foreach($part in $FDQN.Split(".")) {

        $dn = $dn + "DC=$part"
        $index++

        if( $index -ne $FDQN.Split(".").Count) {
            $dn = $dn + ","
        }
    }    
    return $dn
}

$currentPath=Split-Path ((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value).MyCommand.Path
[xml]$configFile = Get-Content "$currentPath\WindowsUpdateOMatic.xml"

# Process each domain specified in the configuration file
foreach ($domain in $configFile.domains.domain) {

    # Retrieve excluded hosts from configuration file
    $excludedHosts = @()
    $xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//host[@exclude=`"true`"]/@name")
    foreach($node in Select-Xml -Xpath $xpath $configFile){        
        $excludedHosts += ,@($node.ToString())
    }

    # Retrieve excluded org units from the configuration file
    $excludedOrgUnits = @()
    $xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//orgunit[@exclude=`"true`"]/@name")    
    foreach($node in Select-Xml -Xpath $xpath $configFile){      
        $excludedOrgUnits += ,@($node.ToString())
    }

    $hostsToUpdate = @()

    # Retrieve org units within the current domain in the 
    # configuration file, ignoring org units with child 
    # elements

    # Process childless org units
    $xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//orgunit[@exclude=`"false`"][not (*)]")
    foreach($orgUnit in (Select-Xml -Xpath $xpath $configFile)){      
        $distinguishedName = "OU=" + $orgUnit.Node.name + "," + $distinguishedName

        # Ignore excluded org units
        if(-not ($excludedOrgUnits -contains $orgUnit.Node.name)) {

            # Get parent org units ready to interrogate AD                
            $parent = $orgUnit.Node.ParentNode      
            while($parent.localname -eq "orgunit") {
                $distinguishedName = $distinguishedName + "OU=" +  $parent.name + ","

                if(-not ($parent.ParentNode -eq $null)) {
                    $parent = $parent.ParentNode
                }
                else {
                    break
                } #ENDIF
            } #ENDWHILE
        $distinguishedName = $distinguishedName + (FDQNtoDN($domain.name).ToString())
        $hostsToUpdate += (Get-ADComputer -server $domain.name -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' -SearchBase "$distinguishedName"  -SearchScope OneLevel | Select -expand DNSHostName)
    } #ENDIF
Remove-Variable distinguishedName
} #ENDFOREACH $orgUnit

# Retrieve individually specified hosts
$xpath = ("/domains/domain[@name=`"") + ($domain.name) + ("`"]//host[@exclude=`"false`"]")
foreach($hostToUpdate in (Select-Xml -Xpath $xpath $configFile)) {

    # Ignore excluded hosts
    if(-not ($excludedHosts -contains $hostToUpdate.Node.name)) {
        $hostsToUpdate += ($hostToUpdate.Node.name) + (".") + ($domain.name)
    }
} #ENDFOREACH $host

# Apply updates and reboot each host
foreach($hostToUpdate in $hostsToUpdate) {

    # Attempt to find host in Nagios. If exists, put host into downtime

    # If IIS box, drain stop from Apache2 Load Balancer

    # Apply Updates

    # Reboot & Wait a short period of time

    # Check whether host is alive

    # If IIS box: (N.B. NAnt scripts exist for some of this)
        # start IIS gracefully
        # warm up
        # run rudimentary checks # apache readd probably does a calc
        # re-add to Apache2 Load Balancer

    # If applicable, Remove Nagios Downtime
}

$hostsToUpdate
Remove-Variable hostsToUpdate
```

} #